# Best way to rename .jpg files as per naming convention

Tags: file, jpeg, renaming

In my HTML page, I am showing c**urrent day and last 4 days reports**. I have already designed HTML page. But for every day, I have hard-coded the JPG Image filename.

I am using **naming convention** as follows -

1. For **Current Day**, CurDt_S1
2. For Current Day **minus 1 day**, CurDt_1_S1
3. For Current Day **minus 2 days**, CurDt_2_S1
4. For Current Day **minus 3 days**, CurDt_3_S1
5. For Current Day **minus 4 days**, CurDt_4_S1

Now, I want to rename a series of .jpg but i want to append the string at the end of file name. Please help me how can I achive this. **Through vbscript or HTML or batch file.**

I tried using batch file but it is not working for me.

**Series of jpg files** - CurDt_S1, CurDt_S2, CurDt_S3 etc.. uptill S20.

- CurDt_S1 will be renamed as CurDt_1_S1 uptill S20
- CurDt_**1**_S1 to CurDt_2_S1 uptill S20
- CurDt_**2**_S1 to CurDt_3_S1 uptill S20
- CurDt_**3**_S1 to CurDt_4_S1 uptill S20
- CurDt_**4**_S1 files will be archived to a diff folder or would be deleted

Any SIMPLE solution which i can code is welcome. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, HTML won't be able to offer anything for this. It is a markup language, not a programming language.

In visual basic, you have a lot of options though. Firstly, you want to be changing the filename, which you can do using

```
   My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(fileX, fileY)
```

In the case of Cur_Dt_4_s1 you would be using

```
  My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile("C:\directory1\file.txt","C:\directory2\file.txt")
```

To handle the name changes, first create a loop which will run through the folder of these jpegs.

Next, load each file in order, using a method from the [path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get collect the entire path for each file as a string.  As you have maintained a standard naming system for your files, all it takes is:

```
 result = Path.GetFileName(fileName); //result being a string
```

and then, because the string "result" is already an array of chars access the 6th character (your number) by using:

```
 Dim charNum = result(5)
```

To change 'charNum' to an integer, use

```
 CInt(charNum)
```

After that it's pretty simple. You'll +1 the variable you made from CInt-ing the number, then converting it back to a character with CChar, pushing it back in to the array in the same position, and then using that new string as the variable you will have for the fileY string.

Hopefully you can explore this a little better yourself, but I will construct the code properly if you are still struggling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I do not have any option of VB etc. It has to be simple and free of cost, free of any sw installation. Can we do it thru javascripting in HTML or batch file?

Comment: My bad, I saw VBscript and read it as VB. Do you have access to windows powershell? It will be difficult in normal command prompt; it's the sort of task I'd code properly or use linux for. I will see if I can figure it out in Javascript but I don't think it will be particularly easy...

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the SIMPLEST way to achieve this bu using BATCH FILE in simplest way.

By Using following code -

del CurDt_5_S*
ren CurDt_4_S* CurDt_5_S*
ren CurDt_3_S* CurDt_4_S*
ren CurDt_2_S* CurDt_3_S*
ren CurDt_1_S* CurDt_2_S*

I tested it and its working. :) :) :)